# Запуск MainActivity только первый раз, второй и последующие запуски, другая Activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Подскажите пожалуйста, пишу приложение с паролем, по этому есть необходимость чтобы при первом запуске пользователю выводилось окно с созданием пароля, а при втором и последующих, поле с проверкой ранее созданного пароля. Отсюда вопрос, как реализовать чтобы в первый раз запускался один файл activity, а при втором и последующих другой файл activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас есть Splash экран, тогда вставляете в него код проверки авторизации, если пользователь не зарегистрирован, тогда открываете регистрацию, если да, главный экран. В манифесте на запуск должен идти сплеш.

Comment: спасибо, получилось)

Comment: @Medaf Если ответ правильный нажмите на галочку слева ответа

Answer (score 1):

В `onCreate()` с помощью `SharedPreferences`в первый раз шлёте туда данные, и с помощью ветвления реализуете запуск другой активности.

Например вот(тут правда замена фрагмента, но принцип тот же):

```
 SharedPreferences preferencesView = getSharedPreferences("view",MODE_PRIVATE);
    String view = preferencesView.getString("VIEW"," ");

    if (view.equals("settings")){
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, settingsFragment)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit();
    }else{
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, taskFragment)
                .commit();
    }
```